# Magento2 in windows IIS server - Pub/static appends version

Tags: magento2, windows

I have installed magento2 in one of our windows server which uses IIS.

Followed the following blog, which helped for most part

    http://blog.winhost.com/how-to-install-magento-2-1-2-on-winhost-iis/

I ran all the commands that is needed. Ran the main command as well

    php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
However, when i run my application on browser. The css and js will return in 404 error. Here are the few files that gets loaded.

    /pub/static/version1483704562/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/calendar.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

    pub/static/version1483704562/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Here, if you notice. `version1483704562` this version gets added up in URL. Not sure why this occur. The files are actually present, because of this version inclusion it throws error. 

Please let me know on how to solve this. **`NOTE: Application is in windows IIS server`**

Answer (score 0):

IIS convert static folder to Application
and create web config file with following rule

```
        <rules>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 1-1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^version.+?/(.+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="../static.php?resource={R:0}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

The **`version inclusion`** that you have mentioned is not the reason why **css** and **js** links throws an error. 
  
**Static content signing** is a Magento feature that allows you to invalidate the browser cache for static resources. Magento accomplishes this by adding a deployment version to the URL of static files . 
For additional info refer to
[Magento DevDocs][1]

Possible resolution for this issue( js and css throwing 404 not found) :  

 - Make sure upgrade command has been executed **`( php bin/magento setup:upgrade )`** before deploying static content.

  [1]: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cache/static-content-signing.html#static-content-signing